# Variable not incremented in latest Selenium IDE

Tags: variables, increment, selenium-ide

I attempting to increment a variable in the latest Selenium IDE however the variable does not get updated.  Did something change in the latest versions?

---

store | 1 | i

store | javascript{storedVars.i++;}|

echo | ${i}

---

**Log**

Running 'Test increment'

1.store on 1 with value i... OK

'Test increment ' completed successfully

Running 'Test increment ' 
2.store on javascript{storedVars.i++;}... OK

'Test increment' completed successfully

Running 'Test increment ' 
echo: 1

'Test increment' completed successfully

---

Comment: Found this simple and but not satisfying solution: 
'execute script : return parseInt (${ct})  + parseInt(1) | i

Comment: Use prefix increment: execute script | return parseInt (++${i}) | i